# Dynamic output from compute shader

Tags: ios, shader, metal

If I am generating 0-12 triangles in a compute shader, is there a way I can stream them to a buffer that will then be used for rendering to screen?

My current strategy is:

- create a buffer of `float3` of size `threads * 12`, so can store the maximum possible number of triangles;
- write to the buffer using an index that depends on the thread position in the grid, so there are no race conditions.

If I want to render from this though, I would need to skip the *empty memory*. It sounds ugly, but probably there is no other way currently. I know CUDA geometry shaders can have variable length output, but I wonder if/how games on iOS can generate variable-length data on GPU.

**UPDATE 1**:

As soon as I wrote the question, I thought about the possibility of using a second buffer that would point out how many triangles are available for each *block*. The vertex shader would then process all vertices of all triangles of that block.

**This will not solve the problem of the unused memory though and as I have a big number of threads, the total memory wasted would be considerable.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're looking for is the Metal equivalent of D3D's "[AppendStructuredBuffer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff471448(v=vs.85).aspx)". You want a type that can have structures added to it atomically.

I'm not familiar with Metal, but it does support [Atomic operations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/std-lib/std-lib.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014364-CH5-SW2) such as 'Add' which is all you really need to roll your own Append Buffer. Initialise the counter to 0 and have each thread add '1' to the counter and use the original value as the index to write to in your buffer.

Comment: That's exactly what I came up with: increment counter atomically to _reserve_ a specific zone of the buffer, then write on buffer. At the end of the pass, copy buffer to render buffer using atomic int size and delete work buffer.